# Why is tr suppressing my curl response header output entirely when removing new lines?

Tags: http, tr

Why does `tr` not simply replace the newline characters contained in this output?

```
> curl -I www.google.com  2>/dev/null | egrep 'HTTP|Server'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gws
> curl -I www.google.com  2>/dev/null | egrep 'HTTP|Server' | tr '\n' ' '
>
```

It works fine when replacing other characters:

```
> curl -I www.google.com  2>/dev/null | egrep 'HTTP|Server' | tr 'TS' ' '
H  P/1.1 200 OK
 erver: gws
>
```

Answer (score 2):

So this got very clear when I read the right [docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2): HTTP uses carriage return and line feed characters i.e. the lovely `CRLF` for line breaks!

E.g. Removing `\r` and replacing `\n` will do the job:

```
$ curl -I www.google.com  2>/dev/null | egrep 'HTTP|Server' | tr -d '\r' | tr '\n' ' '
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: gws
```

Just removing `\n` will leave the carriage return in your output, which your *nix shell then interprets as returning to the beginning of the same line. I suppose it is the command prompt which then overwrites what was there. Simple!